# To replace value of a column while moving data to other table by referring reference table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Let's take I have a table named 'Table1' having columns and values as below

```
---------------------------
action | component | type |
---------------------------
  1    |     2    |  1    |
  2    |     3    |  3    |
  3    |     4    |  2    |
---------------------------
```

and 'Table2' having exactly same structure as 'table1'.

Now I have an  other table 'reference' as below

```
---------------------------
description | id  | value  |
---------------------------
   action   |  2  |  create|
   action   |  1  |  delete|
   action   |  3  |  update|
  component |  2  |  c1    |
  component |  4  |  c2    |
  component |  3  |  c3    |
   type     |  2  |  t1    |
   type     |  1  |  t2    |
   type     |  3  |  t3    |
---------------------------
```

Now, I need to move data from 'table1' to 'table2' by referring the values from 'reference' table. My resulting table should look like below.

---

```
action | component | type |
---------------------------
delete |     c1    |  t2  |
create |     c3    |  t3  |
update |     c2    |  t1  |
---------------------------
```

Please help me with the query for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Which* SQL are you using? Did you try anything at all before posting?

Comment: Actually i'm trying this is hive query, And what I tried is while selecting I tried replacing particular column with select statement which includes join statement with reference table. But it's not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for multiple joins:

```
select t1a.value as action,
       t1c.value as component,
       t1t.value as type
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1a
     on t2.action = t1a.id and t1a.description = 'action' join
     table1 t1c
     on t2.component = t1c.id and t1c.description = 'component' join
     table1 t1t
     on t2.type = t1t.id and t1t.description = 'type';
```

Comment: thanks bro, you saved my day. I wanted a query in hive and this perfectly works.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this :

```
select 
    (select b.description from reference b where A.action = b.id and b.description = 'action') as action,
    (select c.description from reference c where A.action = c.id and c.description = 'component') as component,
    (select d.description from reference d where A.action = d.id and d.description = 'type') as type
from table_1 A
```

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear? actually, we need to populate data to 'table2' from 'table1' by refering the particular values from 'reference' table.

In Your answer, you're not refering to 'reference' table right?

Comment: @CodingOwl just the name was wrong. check the update